# access arrow data

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am fetching arrow tabular data from an API. The content-type of the response is `application/vnd.apache.arrow.stream`. In my react code, I am trying to read the response as such.

I am not sure if this is the optimized way of reading arrow data.

```
function extractDataFromTable(table) {
    let extractedData = [];
  
    // Iterate over each row of the table
    for (const row of table) {
      const rowJson = row.toJSON();
      if (rowJson.origin_lat instanceof Float64Array) {
        rowJson.origin_lat = Array.from(rowJson.origin_lat)[0]; // Assuming only one element in the array
      }
      if (rowJson.origin_lon instanceof Float64Array) {
        rowJson.origin_lon = Array.from(rowJson.origin_lon)[0]; // Assuming only one element in the array
      }
  
      extractedData.push(rowJson);
    }
  
    return extractedData;
  }


const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/api/new_drives`, {
        params: {
          name: cname,
        },
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
      });
  
 // Convert the response data to an Apache Arrow table
 const buffer = new Uint8Array(response.data);
 const table = tableFromIPC(buffer);
  
 // Process the table to extract your data
 const extractedData = extractDataFromTable(table); 
 data.setApiData(extractedData);
```

Is there a better and faster way of reading arrow data?

Answer (score 1):

## no JSON

```
      const rowJson = row.toJSON();
```

> faster way of reading arrow data?

That `.toJSON()` call looks like it's more expensive than necessary.

Didn't arrow hand you a vector of floats?
Store a bunch of small integers and then
go `x`amine memory in
[gdb](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb) to verify.

Can't you get a pointer into that array?
Or `memcpy()` the values into your own array?

```
      extractedData.push(rowJson);
```

That similarly looks more expensive than storing a float
and bumping an index.